# Is skin care allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sunnah, hijab, makruh

Well,some types of make up or beautification is Haram since they are changing the creation of Allah such as removing eye brows etc.
But if use cosmetics or skin care products to get clear skin and cure pimples,acne,freckles etc.and to make my skin soft without any intention to show myself to na mahram,is it allowed? Is it changing creation of Allah or just curing the defects like acne? What about doing excersise to be fit and loss weight? All these are halal?

Answer (score -1):

Skin care is allowed, both for medicinal purposes and for the purpose of beauty so long as the latter is within the rules of modesty enjoined upon the *ummah*. This is obvious to all Muslims since there is no monasticism in Islam and Muslims are expected to live with one foot in this world, that is to be worldly; and the other foot in the next world, that is to be spiritual.

It's obviously **not** changing Allah's creation, in so far it is creation, as no man can create, in its proper sense (this being the religious interpretation of the conservation laws in physics).